# figuring out width and height, x and y position of image in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

So I have a UIWebView and there is an image showed inside it. The question is, is there any way for me to get the width, height, origin-x, origin-y of this image? I have added a UITapGestureRecognizer. What I want is that when I tap on the image, it gives me this information. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
Why doesn't this work:

```
NSString * widthJs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('imageid').clientHeight;"
];
    NSString * heightJs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('imageid').clientWidth;"
                          ];

    NSString *width = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:widthJs];
    NSString *height = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:heightJs];
     NSLog(@"Coor height is %@ with coor width is %@", width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked two questions.
Q1: how to interact `UIWebView` with iOS framework?
   `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` is a keyword. and you can find many articles about this by google.
Q2: how to get image informations by javascript?
   [How to get image size (height & width) using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Comment: I am aware of stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, but not so much about the javascript.. how do I put this together?

Comment: also how about the x and y coordinate?